# Exclude result from MySQL query in JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple tables with orders and deliveries and I want to get only open orders (only those orders that do not have records in delivery table).

So, my tables look like:

Orders table (sh_comenzi):

```
id  partner
1   Partner X
2   Partner Y
3   Partner Z
4   Partner Q
```

Order lines table (sh_comenzi_pos) where `idc` is the `id` of `sh_comenzi` table

```
id  idc cPos    quantity
1   1   1       5
2   1   2       10
3   1   3       20
4   2   1       10
5   2   2       15
6   3   1       10
7   3   2       5
8   3   3       8
9   4   1       15
```

The deliveries items table is (sh_delivery_items)

```
id  idc cPos
1   1   1
2   1   3
3   2   2
4   3   1
5   3   2
6   3   3
```

The desired result should give me an output of open orders just like this:

```
id  partner
1   Partner X
2   Partner Y
4   Partner Q
```

The result doesn't have to keep track o quantities, just on lines level. If one line from orders exists in `sh_delivery_items` then that line is closed.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sh_comenzi.id, partner FROM sh_comenzi
LEFT JOIN sh_comenzi_pos ON sh_comenzi.id = sh_comenzi_pos.idc
LEFT JOIN sh_delivery_items ON (sh_comenzi_pos.idc = sh_delivery_items.idc AND sh_comenzi_pos.cPos = sh_delivery_items.cPos)
WHERE sh_comenzi.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY sh_comenzi.id DESC
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: How `sh_comenzi_pos` and `sh_delivery_items`  are related ?

Comment: The 'idc' from sh_delivery_items represents the idc from sh_comenzi_pos, same thing for cPos

Comment: right but `sh_delivery_items` table should have a direct relation with `sh_comenzi_pos` to know if the order is closed or not.

Comment: the 'sh_delivery_items' table keeps all order lines that are closed, so if one line from sh_comenzi_pos exists in that table then the line is closed. I am trying to figure out how to find all orders that still have open lines

Comment: The `sh_delivery_items` is wrong. If it has to contain the lines then it should be like `table(id, id_line)` in order to get which lines are closed

Comment: the link between sh_delivery_items and sh_comenzi_pos is done by idc and cPos together..

Comment: Show the code you wrote so far to get the outcome.

Comment: `sh_comenzi.id` should be never `NULL` :-)

Comment: create a new status_table and do a JOIN from there and then do the statement WHERE status_table.statusid = 1 :-)

Comment: This solution is not desirable, it should use only the data posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the query you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM sh_comenzi c
  INNER JOIN sh_comenzi_pos p
      ON c.id = p.idc
  LEFT JOIN sh_delivery_items di               # 'di' from 'delivery items'
      ON p.idc = di.idc AND p.cPos = di.cPos
WHERE di.id IS NULL                            # keep only not-delivered items
```

#### How it works

It combines all the orders (table `sh_comenzi`) with their line items (table `sh_comenzi_pos`). The `INNER JOIN` will leave out the empty orders (if any); if you need them then use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Next, each row (order, line item) is combined with the delivery information (table `sh_delivery_items`) using the pair of columns (`idc`, `cPos`). The `LEFT JOIN` ensures all the rows from the left side table (or result set) appear in the final result set; if a row from the right side table cannot be found to match the row from the left, a row full of `NULL`s is used instead. This happens for the line items that were not delivered yet (there is no record for them in `sh_delivery_items`).

Then, the `WHERE` clause keeps only the rows having `NULL`s in the `di` table (`sh_delivery_items`), i.e. the line items that were not delivered, together with the orders that own them.

Finally, `SELECT DISTINCT c.*` selects only the columns from the orders table (`sh_comenzi`) and `DISTINCT` ensures each order appear only once. Otherwise, each order appears once for each of its line items that was not delivered.

Complete the query yourself with the desired `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Nice work! There's a typo: in the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN` is p.idc